# Using Fiddler with multiple Azure Web Roles

Tags: azure, fiddler

I have started work on a Windows Azure solution that hosts multiple Web Role projects which talk to each other over HTTP.

When I Debug (F5) my project in Visual Studio two web roles are started on the following IP addresses:

- 127.0.0.1
- 127.0.0.2

When I run Fiddler I listen to traffic being sent to 127.0.0.1 by using the built in ipv4.fiddler hook.

How do I listen to the traffic being sent to on 127.0.0.2?

Comment: How do the web roles communicate?

Comment: Raw HTTP using the new System.Net.Http stack.

Comment: There's nothing very special about the "ipv4.fiddler" trick-- it simply turns the Host header into "127.0.0.1" when the "ipv4.fiddler" hostname is received. In Fiddler, you could just click Tools > HOSTS and add a new rule like MyOtherInstance 127.0.0.2 and then use http://MyOtherInstance.

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks that worked perfectly. If you had added it as an answer I would mark it correct.

Answer (score 2):

What I would suggest is not to use the ipv4.fiddler at all.  Instead, configure you 2 webroles appropriately.

I assume that your web roles communicate over standard HTTP, and I guess you're using standard .NET approaches to communicate.  Why not configure these mechanisms to use a proxy, in this case the fiddler proxy.  By default this would be 127.0.0.1:8888  This means you will capture the traffic between the 2 roles.